# If $f$ surjective and $ f\circ g$ surjective, is $g$ also surjective?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

> Let $f\colon C\to B$ surjective and $g\colon A\to C$ a function. If $f\circ g$ is surjective, is $g$ also surjective ?

I would say it is, but I can't prove it, so may be it's wrong. I just need an answer as "yes" or "no", not a proof. I'll manage after for the proof.

Comment: You cannot compose $f$ and $g$ as they now stand. And the question $\neq$ what the title says? Maybe $g$ goes from $B$ to $A$ instead?

Comment: In your title you ask a different question than in the body.

Comment: Ahem... I think you messed up a couple of things with the compositions... If $f:C\to B$ and $g:A\to B$ neither $g\circ f$ nor $f\circ g$ exist.

Comment: It's $g:A\to C$. I corrected it

Comment: **After the edit:** definitely no. Let $B=\{0\}$, let $f$ the constant map $\equiv 0$ and $g$ any map $A\to C$. $f\circ g\equiv 0$, but $g$ needn't be surjective.

Answer (score 2):

In problems like these it is sometimes clarifying to try very simple cases. Consider the sets $A = \{1\} , C =\{1,2\}, B = \{1\}$. Then say $g(1) = 1$ and $f(1) = f(2) = 1$. Is $f \circ g$ surjective? Is f surjective? Is g surjective?

Answer (score 1):

Take $A=B=C=\mathbb{R}$, $f\colon \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ and $g\colon \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ defined by:
$$
f(x) = \begin{cases}
\tan x & \text{ if } x\in (-\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2})\\
0 & \text{ otherwise.}
\end{cases}
$$
and $g(x) = \arctan x$. Are $f$ and $f\circ g$ surjective? But is $g$ surjective?

Answer (score 0):

No, it does not imply that.

Suppose $f : Y \to Z$ is surjective. Let's construct a counter example. It may be possible that we can restrict $f$ to a domain $E \subset Y$ such that $f : E \to Z$ is surjective (Intuitively, we got rid of some points $p \in Y$ which map to a point in $Z$ that is mapped to be some other point $q \in Y$. $E$ is then made up of these leftover $q$. This is possible when $f$ is not injective).

Now, we can take a non-surjective $g : X \to Y$ that only maps to points in $E$. This makes $g \circ f$ surjective.

This is intuition behind the result. We can easily construct a simple example.

Take $f : \{1, 2, 3\} \to \{10, 11\}$ with $f(1) = 10, f(2) = 11, f(3) = 10$. Take $g : \{0, 1,\} \to \{1, 2, 3\}$, and $g(0) = 1, g(1) = 2$. Then $f\circ g(0) = 10, f\circ g(1) = 11$ such that $f\circ g$ is surjective, but $g$ is not.